# Lock screen rotation depending on screen size

Tags: android, android-screen-support, screen-rotation

I'm working on an app which requires to be locked to landscape if the device is a tablet and locked to portrait if the device is a phone. Is there some clean way to do this besides checking on every activity start?

Comment: "I'm working on an app which requires to be locked to landscape if the device is a tablet and locked to portrait if the device is a phone" -- in a word, yuck.

Comment: @CommonsWare I agree. My client doesn't.

Comment: I also can't stand apps that are restricted to portrait.

Comment: I also can't stand apps that are restricted to landscape.

Comment: I have no power there. My client was really specific about it and I cannot afford to lose this project.

Answer (score 4):

I've found this post two years later. I had to do exactly the same and this is what I did:

1 - Don't declare `screenOrientation` attribute anywhere in the *AndroidManifest.xml*.
    2 - Create folders *res/layout* and *res/layout-w600dp*.
    3 - Create folders *values* and *values-w600dp*.
    4 - Create *values/layout.xml* with the following content:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
</resources>
```

5 - Add the same file to *values-w600dp* changing `isTablet` to `true`:

```
<resources>
     <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

6 - Retrieve this value in every activity and change rotation depending on whether the device is a tablet or not:

```
// Locks the screen orientation to horizontal if it's a tablet
if (context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet)){
    activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);

// Locks the screen orientation to vertical if it's a smartphone
} else {
    activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** Since we didn't specify the `screenOrientation` attribute earlier, each time an activity is loaded, Android will first search for a layout suitable for the device's current orientation, even before the activity has had any time to run your screen orientation change code, and it will fail if it can't find it.

For example, let's suppose you don't want to allow portrait orientation. If the device is in portrait orientation while you launch your application or a new activity is started, it will first search for a portrait layout for the activity, then execute your screen orientation change snippet and eventually change the portrait layout for the landscape one. It will do it very fast though, so you won't notice, but still it needs to find a portrait layout or else it will crash.

So you must let the system find both layouts by either not using `land` or `port` density qualifiers in your layout folder's names, or, if this is necessary by providing both a *layout-land* and a *layout-portrait* folder with every layout inside, even if they are duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter said, you might want to think about whether that is really the best approach or not.  Anyway, assuming it's a worthwhile endeavor:

You can either lock screen in the AndroidManifest.xml file or in the individual Activity code.

e.g. 
XML

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.activity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

JAVA

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

so you could do something like:

```
// get dimensions 
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
//whatever you want
int width=metrics.widthPixels;
int height=metrics.heightPixels;
int dens=metrics.densityDpi;

//compare dimensions to some pre-set value
if ( /*  device fits dimensions constraints for tablet for your purposes */) {
    //lock orientation
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
else {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

maybe make a helper function that receives device metrics or dimensions as input and returns true if it falls in the tablet range

Comment: Right now I'm loading a boolean from resources which is kind of an easier way to do this. I just wanted to know if there's a way to do this directly in the manifest instead of having to hack it away.

Comment: what boolean from resources?  there is no logic or conditionals int he manifest so you either set something in the manifest or you don't.  i would recommend implementing a custom activity class that does the above logic in the onCreate, and having each of your activityies extned that custom class and call the super in their onCreate.  that way you only have to write the code once